# Tao Group virtual processor assembly

Tags: assembly

Several years ago (between 1996 and 2001 I think) there was a company, based in Reading UK, called Tao. They were eventually bought out (probably by some part of M$).

They created an OS called Taos, which used executables which were compiled for a VP (virtual processor). The VP exe would be converted at run-time to machine code for the target machine. The resultant code ran much faster than Java bytecode would (at the time).

You could program in C/C++ and Java, but the most fun thing was that they had a VP macro assembler. It allowed for infinite registers and you could reference libraries and jump into other functions in a really intelligent, elegant and incredible way.

My question is: Are there any similar VP Macro Assembler technologies out there in current use?

Comment: I remember these. I had a cover disc (CD) from some magazine with the OS on. You copied the whole Taos OS onto a floppy disk and booted from it. It was amazing, it had a Quake clone in it, an MPEG video player and several graphical demos. You could open several of these windows at a time and they would all run smoothly. This was at a time when opening two MPEG videos (or similar) in Windows 98 would slow it to a crawl.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I don't remember it having Quake (?) but yes, the demos were very graphics intensive and it all ran better than anything I had experienced at the time. The Taos operating system made it into quite a lot of devices, like mobile phones and set-top boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taos 'virtual processor code' to native machine code translator seems very similar to Microsoft's .NET CIL bytecode translator. Maybe also it's like Google's Java bytecode to Android Dalvik "dexer". You can probable program in either CIL assembly or Java bytecode somehow. I'm just wondering why you would want to?

Comment: It was nice to program in an old-school kind of freedom, without any of the drawbacks. The VP asm language was very advanced, with structures (instead of classes) and other great features I most forget now.

Comment: It seems like a step backward though? What about stepping forward into functional languages like Haskell or F#?

Comment: Haskell is fun, I like it. I don't see the Tao Group's VP asm as a "step backward" because it was way more powerful than assemblers used to be, in terms of flexibility and features.